# Rails find_by with OR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

I have a named scope set up in my rails application that is used to locate a record either by its ID (directly from the index view) or a UUID (from an email - basically only so that users can't enter in any ID and view a record)

```
scope :by_uuid, lambda { |id| where('id = ? OR uuid = ?', id, id) }
```

This is used in the show action, so the ID comes from the url, like

```
services/114

services/74c083c0-8c29-012f-1c87-005056b42f8a
```

This works great, until you get a UUID such as 74c083c0-8c29-012f-1c87-005056b42f8a
This, rails unfortunately converts to the int value and we get services/74 AS WELL AS the record with the correct UUID

Adding a .first to the scope will not help because the order could be different for each record, so that does not work.

Is there a way to prevent rails from converting the ID like this and taking the string literally? Obviously, there will not be a record with an ID that matches that, but if it goes willy-nilly with the integer values of the string passed to it, we could get anything back.

Using the dynamic finders, such as

```
Service.find_by_uuid
```

or

```
Service.find_by_id
```

work as intended, however we need to be able to retrieve a record using the UUID OR the ID in the same method (show).

Is there a way to do something like

```
Service.find_by_id_or_uuid
```

Comment: Your original idea to use a named scope with a lambda function should work. Are you sure you don't have a bug in the code though? it seems like it should be scope :by_uuid, lambda { where('id = ? OR uuid = ?', id, uuid) } - you have id as both parameters in the parameterized query in your question.

Comment: Yes, because the id is coming from the URL string - so we could have services/114 or services/74c083c0-8c29-012f-1c87-005056b42f8a and it needs to respond to both, I actually left out the |id| declaration. I edited the post above to clarify. The problem is that it's getting the int value of the UUID string and pulling up services/74 instead of the correct record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We fixed this issue with the following change to the scope:

```
scope :by_uuid, lambda { |id| where('binary id = ? OR uuid = ?', id, id) }
```

This ensures that the id string is taken by its binary value instead of being converted into an int. However, this will **ONLY WORK WITH MYSQL BASED APPS**